# Spring batch - overriding jobrepository in context.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-batch

Like described in the linked article below, with Java configuration it is possible to override the JobRepository bean by extending DefaultBatchConfigurer and overriding createJobRepository.

How can this be achieved in a context.xml file where the jobrepository bean is defined like this

```
<bean id="jobRepository_new"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="databaseType" value="Oracle" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource-batch" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="tablePrefix" value="BATCH_" />
    <property name="lobHandler" ref="oracleLobHandler" />
</bean>
```

?

[Can't serialize access for this transaction when running single job, SERIALIZED isolation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55339675/cant-serialize-access-for-this-transaction-when-running-single-job-serialized/75059802#75059802)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike with the Java configuration style, there is nothing provided by default (that you can override) when you use the XML configuration style.

So you just need configure the job repository bean as needed like shown in the snippet you shared.

Comment: I see;  would it work with this annotation as described in the docs:   @EnableBatchProcessing(isolationLevelForCreate = "ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ") ?   What I intend to solve is the isolation level, and this annotation would set it for the default jobrepository as I understand.   If it works I could delete the jobrepositorybean  from the xml (which actually is not even used)   .                                           .

Comment: ok I see, you seem to be mixing XML and annotation configs, which was not mentioned in the initial question. So if you use the annotation, then yes, that should work and you can safely remove the XML definition of the job repository.